# Emacs: how to get rid of the unwanted tab in perl-mode yasnippet

Tags: emacs, yasnippet, cperl-mode

I have the following yasnippet in perl-mode to create a sub:

```
#name : sub ... { ... }
#key: sub
# --
sub ${1:function_name}
# {{{
{
    $0
}
# }}}
```

But when Emacs expands it, it generates an unwanted tab:

```
sub function_name
    # {{{ <-- ?
{

}
# }}}
```

I don't don't have this tab in the snippet definition, so it seems, that it is added by cperl-mode (perl-mode yasnippets are activated in cperl-mode). How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert a snippet, indentation is performed automatically. Add a line to your snippet to prevent this behavior as follows:

```
#name : sub ... { ... }
#key: sub
#expand-env: ((yas-indent-line 'fixed))
# --
sub ${1:function_name}
# {{{
{
    $0
}
# }}}
```

Comment: What version of yasnippet are you using? Did you reload everithing? Where is your snippet located?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I compiled the snippets, and the cached version was used. Now it works. How can I force-recompile the yasnippets, every time I change any of them? Or is it a subject for a separate question?

Comment: I just use `yas-reload-all` when I am working on my snippets.